# Is there a way we can use Selenium on Google Colab like in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I've been using Selenium with Jupyter notebook (with Chrome webdriver) for a while. Using it on Jupyter NB, a new automated window is opened and I can see my code at work which is a great utility when the automation includes selecting an option from a drop down or such.
But while using Selenium (with Chrome web driver) on Google Colab, a new automated tab/window is not opened and I can't really see what my code is doing. Feels like being in a dark cave without a Torch.

**Can anyone tell me how can I see an automated tab of the code while using Selenium on Colab?**

This is what I have tried till now:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://www.python.org")
```

and this too

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update 
!apt install chromium-chromedriver

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```